# How do I sync music with Banshee and my iOS 5 device?

Tags: banshee, ipod

I upgraded my Ipod and now I want to sync music with banshee. Any way that I could sync music to it? I tried syncing and ended up messing up the songs. I have an iPod Touch 4th Gen with iOS 5.0

Answer (score 4):

At present it seems banshee does not support iOS 5 due to 'libgpod' not supporting iPhone 4 or the iPod touch 4G.

See the [Sourceforge release notes](http://gtkpod.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=gtkpod/libgpod;a=blob;f=NEWS;h=def943e094b551ba90ff565a866b1cc0ac648407;hb=HEAD) for more info